# Date and time regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I'm looking for a regular expression which matches the following datetime format:

```
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss (15-Sep-2011 16:00:47)
```

Currently I only have the regex for date which looks something like this:

```
^(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])[\s{1}|\/|-](Jan|JAN|Feb|FEB|Mar|MAR|Apr|APR|May|MAY|Jun|JUN|Jul|JUL|Aug|AUG|Sep|SEP|Oct|OCT|Nov|NOV|Dec|DEC)[\s{1}|\/|-]\d{4}$
```

Any ideas for the time part?

**It's ok guys I found the solution. Submitting for anyone who wants to utilise it.**

```
(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])[\s{1}|\/|-](Jan|JAN|Feb|FEB|Mar|MAR|Apr|APR|May|MAY|Jun|JUN|Jul|JUL|Aug|AUG|Sep|SEP|Oct|OCT|Nov|NOV|Dec|DEC)[\s{1}|\/|-]\d{4}\s(20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d
```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer below. Then people can vote on it and then you can mark it as the correct answer if no one comes up with a better one.

Comment: That regex could be simplified quite a lot. I think `([012]?\d|[123]0|31)([\s/-])(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\1\d{4}\s(2[0-3]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d` with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` turned on is closer to what you mean.

Comment: @JustinMorgan tried your solution but not working even with lower case. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joel suggested above that I should add my solution as an answer here.
So here it is:

```
(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])[\s{1}|\/|-](Jan|JAN|Feb|FEB|Mar|MAR|Apr|APR|May|MAY|Jun|JUN|Jul|JUL|Aug|AUG|Sep|SEP|Oct|OCT|Nov|NOV|Dec|DEC)[\s{1}|\/|-]\d{4}\s(20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d
```

Do let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

*Must it be a regex?*

[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) will work much better.

```
DateTime myDate;
// dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss (15-Sep-2011 16:00:47)
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAsString, 
                          "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                          new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out myDate))
{  ... }
```

Comment: Yes it must be as I'm reading from file and the date time could be embedded on any random line.

Answer (score 0):

Err, it appears to me that the *date* bit is the hard one :-) But you can use the same methods for the time.

Assuming you have two fixed digits, you can use something like:

```
(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

The first bit is the slightly tricky bit since you want one of:

- `0` or `1` followed by a digit.
- `2` followed by `0` thru `3`.

The minutes and seconds are both:

- `0` thru `5` followed by `0` thru `9`.

If you want to allow single-digit hours, just replace `[01]` with `[01]?`.

You may also want to consider the possibility that people may enter `nov` or `OcT` as the month, rendering your regex less useful.

This could be solved with a case-insensitive version which would also reduce the size of the regex as well, requiring only one string per month.