# c# Regex Date in brackets

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I have a sequence and i want to find all of the date entries in it.

The date entries have a format of [27 May 2014 11:07 by Daniel]

How do i form the regex to find this sequence?

[ (Date) by (Name) ]

Where (Date) and (Name) are variable.

Date is always of form DD MM YYYY HH:mm.
Name is an n length string without spaces.

This post ([Date and time regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479435/date-and-time-regular-expression)) uses....

(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])[\s{1}|/|-]
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)
[\s{1}|/|-]\d{4}\s(20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):
[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d

... to find a date time of this format. No, how do we encapsulate this to find the entire sequence?

How to combine with the rest of the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy as pie...<sup>not really</sup>

```
\[0*([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (201[4-9]|20[2-9][0-9]|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|[3-9][0-9]{3}) ((?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]){2}:(?:0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])) by (\w+)\]
```

http://regex101.com/r/nU4uJ6

Answer (score 2):

Assume the format is as it is, this should do the job : 
`@"\[(?<Date>.+) by (?<Author>.+)\]"`

An example to access the `Named Group` :

```
var m = Regex.Match("[27 May 2014 11:07 by Daniel]", @"\[(?<Date>.+) by (?<Author>.+)\]");
var date = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["Date"].Value);
var author = m.Groups["Author"].Value;
```